# Custom Bootstrap 3 Navbar - Justify Links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So after reading several similar questions and some trial and error (mostly error) I am still trying to get this sorted out.

The links on the custom nav bar we created are left justified.

|link link link link ....................... | (all left justified)

What we are trying to achieve is evenly spaced links within the custom nav bar.

| link .... link ..... link ..... link .... link | (where they spread out evenly like so.

The css is included. Not certain where I am going wrong but any help would be appreciated.

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: #4c8917;
  border-color: #3c6d12;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(#64b51e), to(#4c8917));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #64b51e, 0%, #4c8917, 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #64b51e 0%, #4c8917 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #64b51e 0%, #4c8917 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff64b51e', endColorstr='#ff4c8917', GradientType=0);
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #3c6d12;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(#3c6d12), to(#54981a));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c6d12, 0%, #54981a, 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3c6d12 0%, #54981a 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c6d12 0%, #54981a 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff3c6d12', endColorstr='#ff54981a', GradientType=0);
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-custom .navbar-form {
  border-color: #3b6a12;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #3c6d12;
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
  border-top-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-bottom-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 767) {
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #3c6d12;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML or use http://bootply.com?

Comment: Have you tried using the Bootstrap `nav-justified` class? http://www.bootply.com/105175

Comment: Indeed I have used nag-justified. Does not make a difference.

http://www.bootply.com/116648 (per request)

Thank you for taking the time to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Play with the spacing until you get the one you want.

Comment: Half way there! Now it is centered but only centered would like to achieve true justification to fill up the lot of the space.
Bootply link here http://www.bootply.com/117129

Comment: please post only the updated css to your file and not the entire 6000 lines of Bootstrap css (bootply already adds that). I added the class to the style sheet and it worked for me. You will have to adjust the pixels for different screen size.

Comment: All done. Updated boot ply. . . http://www.bootply.com/117382  << point of focus @media (min-width: 768px;) this is where it began to center now just the matter of evenly spreading everything out to work with the responsiveness of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile Bootstrap with Less, you can use the following code:

```
.nav.navbar-nav {
&:extend(.nav-justified all);
}
```